# How to use dispatch queue to run function

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to figure out how to get a database fetch to run in the background. Below are the foreground and background version of the same function. The foreground version works. But in the background version the local variable retval never gets assigned. Putting a breakpoint in the pageInfoForPageKey function tells me that function is never called.

Is self available inside the block?

```
//foreground version
- (PageInfo*)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    return [[self dataController] pageInfoForPageKey:[[[self pageIDs] objectAtIndex:idx] integerValue]];
}

//background version
- (PageInfo*)objectAtIndex:(NSInteger)idx
{
    __block PageInfo* retval = nil;
    __block NSInteger pageID = [[[self pageIDs] objectAtIndex:idx] integerValue];

    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
        retval = [[self dataController] pageInfoForPageKey:pageID];
    });

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

By using `dispatch_async`, you are telling the system that you want it to run your block some time soon, and that **you don't want to wait for your block to finish** (or even start) before `dispatch_async` returns.  That is the definition of asynchronous.  That is the definition of “in the background”.

The system is doing what you told it to: it is arranging for your block to run, and then it is returning **immediately**, before the block has run.  So the block doesn't set `retval` before you `return retval`, because the block hasn't run yet.

If you want to run the database fetch in the background, you need to change your API to pass `retval` back (to whoever needs it) at a later time, after the block has run.  One way is to pass a completion block as a message argument.  This is a common pattern for performing fetches in the background.  For example, look at [`+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10).

You might do it like this:

```
- (void)fetchObjectAtIndex:(NSIndex)idx completion:(void (^)(PageInfo *))block {
    block = [block copy]; // unnecessary but harmless if using ARC
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSInteger pageKey = [[[self pageIDs] objectAtIndex:idx] integerValue];
        PageInfo* pageInfo = [[self dataController] pageInfoForPageKey:pageKey];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            block(pageInfo);
        });
    });
}
```

Then you need to change the caller of `objectAtIndex:` to use this new API instead.

Comment: Incidentally, the [Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) video from WWDC 2012 has some good tips for running things in the background.